# algorithm to generate random position for game object

Tags: algorithm, random

I want to  generate a position for objects in random manner and i don't want them to overlap with each other . 
my screen  width is `4.8` meter and height is `9.6` meter and the object width is `0.5`,and height is `0.5` meter .

can any one put me on the right direction ,or any suggestion .

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can live with your "random" object positions being on a grid, then you can divide the space into 0.5 meter by 0.5 meter squares and pick a square. Your world is 9.6 meters by 4.8 meters. So you have a grid that is 19 x 8.

Put all of the grid positions into a list. For each object that you want to place, randomly pick a grid position from the list and remove it from the list.

If you want to avoid the strict grid appearance, you can alter the x and y positions of your grid centers slightly (add a little here and there). Logically you still have a grid, but the appearance would be less regular.

Comment: i got this idea before is it the best way ??? or there is more intelligent way ?? sorry for my question but it's my first time developing a game

Comment: @Nammari: I don't know if it's the *best* way, but it's effective, simple to implement, and fast to execute. I would suggest using this way to start. Once you have other more important parts of your game working, you can revisit this if it's a problem.

Comment: You can split the grid into smaller blocks. Check all the blocks the object is going to occupy. If available, mark all the blocks under the object. This won't work if you want to fill the whole screen with objects. Then you rather want to run through the screen, and fill it with random objects.

Answer (score 4):

Possible algorithm:

```
1. Choose random coordinates for all objects.
2. Test for overlap. If it occurs, repeat step 1.
```

Possible improvements:

```
1. Reposition overlapping objects with new random coordinates until there is no 
   overlap.
2. Shift any overlapping objects to make them not overlap. Do this intelligently 
   to avoid bunching, if necessary.
```

Comment: Depending on your definition of "random", improvement #2 could lead to "bunched up" objects. Also improvement #1 could run for a VERY long time, if the space is near full.

Answer (score 1):

<s>You don't happen to mention your programming environment or language, but assuming a function `random()` that returns a random value between 0.0 and 1.0 and assuming that you position the object by the upper left corner, you could use the following formula:</s>

```
x = random() * (screenWidth - objectWidth);
y = random() * (screenHeight - objectHeight);
```

I apologize, your post must have changed to read overlap each other.  When I initialy read it, it read overlap the screen width/height.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Goldshteyn suggests, testing for overlap and generate new coordinates if overlap occurs is a good solotion.

If you just have just a few objects you could store them in a list and for every new object test for overlap .

One way to test for overlaps may be to use a boolean array, representing each pixel on the screen. The lookup would be fast then.

Btw isn't a 9.6 meter screen a very big screen?

Comment: it's frustum width and height not a screen

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
bool found = false;
real x;
real y;
do
{
    x = random * (4.8 - 0.5); // Rather make it variables
    y = random * (9.6 - 0.5);

    found = false;
    foreach (obj in objs)
    {
        if (x > obj.x && x < x+0.5 && y > obj.y && obj.y < y+0.5)
        {
             found = true;
             break;
        }
    }
}
while (found == true)
```

Option 2:
Create a 2D array of that represent the sceen. Make the type a ref to the objects.
As you put down, ref to the objects.
You can then just check the array if there is a collision.

With the second option collision detection is much quicker, but it uses more memory.

Comment: using x as int  will it assigns a float value what will happen dude ?